# what is the purpose of split-by <column> --target-dir in Sqoop

Tags: hadoop

What happens internally when we write `--split-by` in sqoop?

Example:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password training123 --query 'select * from  transaction where $CONDITIONS' --split-by Txnid --target-dir input/transaction
```

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop MAP Reduce is all about divide and conquer  .

In order to partition data into multiple independent slices that will be transferred in a parallel manner, Sqoop needs to find the minimum and maximum value of the column specified in the --split-by parameter

When using the split-by option, you should choose a column which contains values that are uniformly distributed.

in the query we are telling  data is evenly distributed on base column 'Txnid' and use the column for making splits.

Answer (score 2):

**--split-by** : It is used to specify the column of the table used to generate splits for imports. This means that it specifies which column will be used to create the split while importing the data into your cluster. It can be used to enhance the import performance by achieving greater parallelism. Sqoop creates splits based on values in a particular column of the table which is specified by --split-by by the user through the import command. If it is not available, the primary key of the input table is used to create the splits.

**Reason to use :** Sometimes the primary key doesn't have an even distribution of values between the min and max values(which is used to create the splits if --split-by is not available). In such a situation you can specify some other column which has proper distribution of data to create splits for efficient imports.

Answer (score 1):

`--split-by <column-name>` - Column of the table used to split work units

Reference: [Sqoop User Guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html)

It specifies which column will be used to create the split while importing the data into your cluster. It can be used to enhance the import performance by achieving greater parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop creates splits based on values in a particular column of the table which is specified by --split-by by the user through the import command. If it is not available, the primary key of the input table is used to create the splits. We can choose the column through --split-by which can result in the best splitting and thus increasing parallelism and better performance.

Answer (score 0):

**split-by** in sqoop is used to create input splits for the mapper. It is very useful for parallelism factor as splitting imposes the job to run faster.